# Symfony2 + Twig : Can't access form rows outside "body" block?

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

i'm a beginner into Symfony2 and i hope that the community could help me and another peoples with this problem.

I have 2 forms sent to the views, that i render these 2 into 2 differents blocks (main-col and left-col), in fact main-col contains user profile form and left-col contains form to upload the profile picture .. This way the profile picture won't appear

But when the profile picture is into the main-col (body block), it works ...

There is some examples for better understand :

**This example will NOT work :**

```
{% extends 'FOOBAR\QuoteMachineBundle::base.html.twig' %}


{% block menu -%}
    {% include 'FOOBAR\QuoteMachineBundle::CompanyProfile/menu.html.twig' %}
{% endblock %}

{% block title -%}Edit company{% endblock %}

{% block leftcol -%}

    <h3>Company Logo</h3>
    {{ form(picture_form) }}

    Current Picture :<br/>
    <img class="opttool" src="{{ entity.pictureWebPath }}" alt="" />

{% endblock %}


{% block body -%}
    {{ form(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

**But this one WILL**

```
{% extends 'FOOBAR\QuoteMachineBundle::base.html.twig' %}


{% block menu -%}
    {% include 'FOOBAR\QuoteMachineBundle::CompanyProfile/menu.html.twig' %}
{% endblock %}

{% block title -%}Edit company{% endblock %}

{% block leftcol -%}

{% endblock %}


{% block body -%}
    {{ form(form) }}



    <h3>Company Logo</h3>
    {{ form(picture_form) }}

    Current Picture :<br/>
    <img class="opttool" src="{{ entity.pictureWebPath }}" alt="" />
{% endblock %}
```

I switched the "current picture form" from leftcol to body ... In fact forms only works in body block.

I should precise that I can use normal variables into leftcol block and that will work. 
The form in leftcol will be an "empty" form element with that only children element :

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
```

How I can render picture_form correctly into leftcol block ??

**EDIT :** Like you asked, i published sample of my base.html.twig

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
                ...
        </head>

        <body>

        <div class="container">

                {% if block('leftcol') is not empty %}
                        <div class="left-col">{% block leftcol %}{% endblock %}</div>
                {% endif %}

            <div class="col-main">
                <h1>{{ block('title') }}</h1>
                <article>
                    {% block body %}{% block fos_user_content %}{% endblock fos_user_content %}{% endblock %}
                </article>
            </div>


                {% if block('rightcol') is not empty %}
                        <div class="right-col">{% block rightcol %}{% endblock %}</div>
                {% endif %}
        </div>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks !

Comment: Please post the base.html.twig you are extending.

Comment: This may problem with leftcol block. Can you please post your part of base.html.twig where you had define leftcol block ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure it will solve your problem but using the `block` method in a IF statement leads to a new request (meaning everything gets called twice). You should try this:

```
    {% set _block = block('leftcol') %}
    {% if _block is not empty %}
       <div class='left-col'> {{ _block|raw }} </div>
    {% endif %}
```

Instead of

```
    {% if block('leftcol') is not empty %}
         <div class="left-col">{% block leftcol %}{% endblock %}</div>
    {% endif %}
```

And do keep in mind that you should put that kind of logic in your controllers whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to make an educated guess, I would say SF/twig are somehow confused by the rendering of two forms inside the same template/block simultaneously. I can't test these two leads right now, but here's what I would try if I were you :

1. Be more precise when calling your two forms in the twig view :

   ```
   <form action="foo" method="post" etc...>
       {{ form(form_picture) }}

       {{ form_rest(form_picture) }}
   {{ form_end(form_picture) }}
   ```

Symfony's form rendering is highly customizable, find all the details here if you haven't discovered them yet : [How to Customize Form Rendering](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html)

2. Use a specific controller, or at least a separate template for at least one of your forms, ideally for each of your forms (but that's a personnal preference) :

   ```
   {% block leftcol %}
       {% render(controller('upload_picture') %}
       // or
       {% include('upload_picture_form.html.twig', with('form':'form_picture') %}
       // Pardon my pseudo-code :P
   {% endblock %}

   {% block body %}
       {{ form(form) }}
   {% endblock %}
   ```